# Stalling $locationChangeStart / $routeChangeSuccess for ajax call response. Global addition of resolve

Tags: angularjs, routes, resolve, route-provider

On each route change I need to check if the user is logged in or not. If not then, I need to redirect the user to the login page otherwise display the page.

I have a parent controller to ng-view :

```
<body ng-controller="init">
<div ng=view=""></div>
</body>
```

Since I need to check if the user is logged in on `all the the route changes, I needed to add the check globally.`

So, I tried to add the check in the init controller like :

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
 CheckSession.get(function(data) {
                                    //user is logged in thus let the user continue
                  },function(data) {
                                     //user is logged out
                                     $location.path('login');
                  });
};
```

The issue with this approach is that:

When the route changes, the page loads for 1-2 seconds as the ajax call success is not received by then and the js does not wait for the ajax call response. Then when it is received and it is a failure then the page redirects to login.

Also I cannot add `event.preventdefault()` in the starting of the $locationChangeStart as that then sends the whole site in an infinite loop.

I NEED:

1. Some way to stall the location change untill and unless the ajax call response is not received.
2. Some way to add this check to all the location changes without having to add the resolve manually to each $route in the routeProvider in app.js.

Comment: why are you not caching the users log in state instead of repetitive calls to your backend?

Comment: I do not have to cache as if the same creds are used on any other system then the first session needs to logout

Comment: I guess you need to use $locationChangeSuccess in the new page.

Comment: new page??? That wil mean adding it on all controllers. redundancy

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `$locationChangeStart` event to the `$rootScope` instead of the `$scope`.
This will make sure you only need to define it once: every page-scope extends internally from the `$rootScope` so the event is known in every page/scope.

As for waiting for the location change, make sure your ajax call is synchronous, if it is asynchronous, your logic will not wait until the call is finished.

Comment: 1. I have defined it only once : In the parent controller of all the controllers.

Comment: 2. If we make the ajax synchronous the whole concept of ajax call is rubbished. Also, I doubt that the way I can stall the change using the  $promise of the ajax call